# Sass::SyntaxError - Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

Ao tentar acessar o site, é exibido esse erro:

Properties are only allowed within rules, directives, mixin includes, or other properties.

https://pastebin.com/LqMyVEM5  (codigo do arquivo sass)

Meu ambiente esta configurado:

ruby 2.4.4

rails 5.2

Sass 3.4.25
bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Randson. Parece que há algumas partes do sass sem formatação. A linha 8446, por exemplo, deveria ser `position: inherit`, imagino, mas está como `osition inherit`.

A 8540 também, está como `h: 40%`. Me parece que o problema é a formatação do seu arquivo de estilo, tente usar algum linter ou validator online para ajudar a encontrar os erros, como esse: http://beautifytools.com/sass-compiler.php